# foreign key sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

i'm having trouble adding a foreign key to my table. Any suggestions would be amazing, thanks :) the errors i am getting are below

```
DROP TABLE Table_One
/

CREATE TABLE Table_One
(
col1 number(10),
col2 varchar(200),
PRIMARY KEY(col1)
)

/
DROP TABLE Table_Two
/

CREATE TABLE Table_Two
(
col3 number(10), 
col2 varchar(200),
PRIMARY KEY(col3),
CONSTRAINT fk_col2 FOREIGN KEY(col2) references Table_One(col2)
)
/

SQL> start newtest.sql

Table dropped.


Table created.
```

> DROP TABLE Table_Two
>              * ERROR at line 1: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

```
CONSTRAINT fk_col2 FOREIGN KEY(col2) references Table_One(col2)
                                                      *
```

> ERROR at line 6: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this
>   column-list

Comment: typo. It should be FOREIGN KEY(col3)

Answer (score 1):

The error on the `DROP TABLE` is because the table doesn't exist yet. The second error is because you have defined `col1` as the primary key of `Table_One`, not `col2`, and a foreign key can only reference a primary or unique key. So, either you need to reference `col1` or you need to create a `unique key` on `col2`.

Comment: @mathguy Updated my answer.